# Convert matlab function to C/C++

Tags: c++, c, matlab, signal-processing

My goal is getting the spectrogram result like [this article](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~juhan/super_spec.html) in C++. They have example `matlab` source code and I want to port them into `C/C++`. Here are 3 `matlab` functions:

- [Blurring function](http://pastebin.com/7XN7Firx)
- [PLCA](http://pastebin.com/Vtc7P09t)
- [STFT](http://pastebin.com/NBA6wJN3)

I tried to use `Matlab Coder` to generate C code and get result like this:[PLCA C](http://pastebin.com/FJv4rTrk)

There were many problems with this converted code: it depends on many lib and functions, there was some methods can't be ported, and I can't build it.
So I decide to port code by hand, and then I faced with other problems:

- The data type in `matlab` is very flexible, for example, the array in matlab can add more columns at anytime, it can contain other array or vector, so it make confuse how to convert it into `C++`
- There were some supported methods/operations in `matlab` and I don't know how to port it into `C++`. For example, `circshift`, `zeros`, divide two matrixes ...

Is there any suggestion?

Comment: I think the best solution is to forget about Matlab, get a good linear algebra library for C++ (like Eigen) and implement the algorithms using that library, rather than looking for C++ analogues for each Matlab functionality.

Comment: Agree with @5gon12eder. Presumably you are porting this to C++ for speed, otherwise you could just keep it in matlab. Your best bet is to look at what the matlab code is doing, and think of the best way to implement that in C++ with the help of a good BLAS library. You could probably optimize it to make use of multi-threading and SIMD instructions, if you knew how to implement those and wanted to take the time.

Comment: As a gold badge holder in MATLAB, this is one of those times where I will side with the majority and discourage you from porting over MATLAB code.  Use a good C++ linear algebra library (Eigen, Armadillo, etc.) instead.  However, you can take a look at the overall logic in the article, but use those ideas and use the functions from the library to port it yourself - don't rely on MATLAB coder.

Comment: @RyanP I use C++ because my app need a C++ code, and I also don't have Matlab license, just use a trial version

Comment: @5gon12eder thank you. I'll think about it, but I'm not good at signal algorithm so I try to port code first. Beside Eigen, do you have any suggestions for me? I really need an advice now

Comment: Do you want to convert to C or to C++? They're two different languages; I suggest you pick one.

Comment: @KeithThompson it isn't a problem. I know the difference between them and I think I can handle it

Comment: Ok, it isn't a problem for you -- but it makes your question unclear and more difficult to answer.

Comment: I'll join the chorus of people recommending that you look for an existing C++ library to do the heavy lifting. I've had good luck with Armadillo; its API is very reminiscent of MATLAB. The documentation includes a handy section describing MATLAB constructs and the Armadillo analogs.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. If you just want to write an isolated C++ code, I'd use a good C++ matrix library like [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/).  Armadillo uses template meta programming to perform some lazy evaluations and is very fast. You'll get their nice interface and some pretty good speed. However, if you plan on doing image processing, I'd use OpenCV's `mat` instead for better portability with their interface/functions.

Comment: If you must port the code, then port it to Fortran, not c/c++ :) Fortran is much closer to Matlab, and modern Fortran has all the C++ features in it and much better for matrix/vector operations. I recommend gfortran.

Comment: @jucestain Thank you, Armadillo looks good for me. Seems it has all things I need. But I have to look at matlab code and port line by line, as I really don't understand the algorithm behind the matlab code above.

Answer (score 0):

I've no experience on matlab coder but we solve this type of problems by using simulink code generator. It may seem weird but works fine. We create a simulink project and add a matlab function block, copy-paste the function there and start code generation.

And of course matlab don't want to show us the key points of their algorithms thats why there are libraries in this method as well.

Comment: You probably have a license for the Matlab coder as well.

Comment: @Daniel yes but never used it

Comment: Also, there's been no need to copy and paste the code into a MATLAB Function Block for some time now. You can just call the function on the MATLAB path like any other.